# Как в python написать "\"? r"\" не работает

Tags: python

Необходимо создавать ссылку на файл и выходит что-то такое:

```
dirfiles = (r"C:\Users\atovarno\Desktop\tic\ticket_" + nnn + r'\')
```

Нашел только то, что можно написать "\ " или "", но я так сделать не могу, потому что позже далее добавлю к этой ссылку другую:

```
dirfiles + x
```

Чтобы в итоге получилось это:

```
C:\Users\atovarno\Desktop\tic\ticket_nnn\x
```

**Вот весь код:**

```
import os, fnmatch, numbers

nnn = input("Введите номер билета ")
nzn = str(nnn) + "_"
listpic = []
dirfiles = (r"C:\Users\atovarno\Desktop\tic\ticket_" + nnn + r'\')
listOfFiles = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\atovarno\\Desktop\\tic\\ticket_" + nnn)  
print(listOfFiles)
pattern = "*.jpg"  
for entry in listOfFiles:  
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
            listpic.append(entry)
print(listpic)


listnum = []
x = 0
while x != "0":
    x = str(input("Введите последовательность номеров "))
    listnum.append(x)

lenofpic = len(listpic)
numberofpic = 0
while numberofpic <= lenofpic:
    numofpic = listnum[numberofpic]
    newname = dirfiles + nzn + numofpic + ".jpg"
    oldname = dirfiles + listpic[numberofpic]
    os.rename(oldname, newname)
```

Comment: [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=os.path.join%20is%3aa)

Comment: Вместо `r'\'` попробуйте `'\\'`

Comment: для склеивания путей существует [специальный инструмент](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)